# UIImageview performance issue

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ipad, uiimageview

i have read various questions about this topic here, even tried too google it. No issue found, fits my problem 1:1 so I try giving it a shot and ask.

The thing is fairly simple:

On my iPad1 i have a UIImageView (700x700) and an image inside. When I swipe across the screen, i change the UIImage every 2 px swiped.

Working with images about the size of 40 kb each, that approach had no issues. Now, that I increased the filesize (450 kb each) this don't work properly any more. Since it works better on Simulator, it tells me, that I have a performance issue - I hope I'm correct here.

I already switched from using imageNamed: since it caches the images and this leads to mem problems.

I'm even down to layer-level, since someone mentioned it would even boost the performance.

Im still not happy, the animation is intend to imitate, is not displayed fluently. Here I'd like to mention, that using animations is not an option - I want the user to drag and determine the animation speed.

Here's some Code:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];

    int xDist = p.x - startTouch.x;

    int res = (xDist)/2;

     if (index + res > 0 && index + res < 98) {

        UIImage *img;
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png", res + index]];            
        img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
        myImageView.layer.contents = (id)img.CGImage;
        diff = res;

    }
}
```

Comment: The file size doesn't matter, the memory used is width * height * 4. If your image is larger than 700x700 it can lead to performances issues, that's why you always need to work with well-sized images.

Comment: That is - in fact - true. My images are now 2000x2000. I did not realize that. Can you elaborate on this a little please? Why does it come to these issues?

Comment: You are using 16Mb memory to display your image but you only need 1.96Mb. Reduce your images using ImageIO.framework. Also imageView is basically using view.layer.content with the CGImage, so it's probably not a big win in term of performances.

Comment: The problem is loading an image, and decompressing it to the raw image data takes time. You could cache the decompressed image or use the image cache by using `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` but this won't help with 2000*2000 images since they need much memory.